# Connection Timed Out using dio package (Local host )

Tags: flutter

I am using dio package to use post method on a local api that my friend developed , first i was getting a socket excpetion but i solved it replacing the `127.0.0.1` with my current ip and ran `php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.105` , after it i got connection timed out , it looks like it's a common error , but i thought maybe my situation is different , this is my dio class :

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

    class DioHelper {
      static Dio? dio;
      static init() {
        dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
          baseUrl: "http://192.168.1.105:8000/api/",
          responseType: ResponseType.json,
          receiveTimeout: 30000,
          connectTimeout: 500000,
          followRedirects: false,
          receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
        ));
      }
    
      static Future<Response> post(
          {required String url,
          Map<String, dynamic>? query,
          Map<String, dynamic>? body}) async {
        return await dio!.post(url, queryParameters: query, data: body);
      }
    }
```

as you can see no matter how long i make the connection timeout period , i still get the same error , please provide some explanation of this error and possible solutions .

Answer (score 2):

Try to run php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 and then
if you are using emulator, use 10.0.2.2 as your base url and if you are using real device then use your ip adress.
Make sure both devices are connected on same port